# JQuery POST with Ajax to overwrite txt file not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, overwrite

I have a site http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/ where I'm posting my programs and games. I have no problem writing code to download a program I made (click on the Programs button then SMS Sender), but I'm rather confused as to how to generate a counter. Before anything, I do not wish to use one from a website, because I'd really like to format it myself. The way I thought of doing this was through the use of a txt file, smssender.txt which simply has:

> 0

Then the javascript of the site which handles the overwrite of the txt file is:

```
$("#downbutton").click(function () {
    downcounter++;
    if (downcounter == 1) $("#counter").text("SMS Sender has been downloaded " + downcounter + " time...");
    else $("#counter").text("SMS Sender has been downloaded " + downcounter + " times...");
    $.post("http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/PHP/smssender.php", {
        counter: downcounter
    }, function (data) {});
});
```

which should call a PHP file, smssender.php, which has but 5 lines:

```
<?php
    $counter = $_POST['counter'];
    file_put_contents("/counters/smssender.txt", $counter);
?>
```

I wish I knew if the php page is being called at all, because the code that changes the text that indicates the download times in the page works well, but as soon as the page is refreshed, the number of downloads goes back to 0, because the 0 is obtained from this code:

```
var downcounter = 0;
$.get("http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/counters/smssender.txt", function (data) {
    downcounter = data;
    if (downcounter == 1) $("#counter").text("SMS Sender has been downloaded " + downcounter + " time...");
    else $("#counter").text("SMS Sender has been downloaded " + downcounter + " times...");
});
```

which clearly indicates no overwrite took place since it successfully retrieves the 0 from smssender.txt (I've previously tried with 1 and 2 and it worked). So why is the code wrong? Any kind of help is truly appreciated. Thanks for your time, and Happy New Year to all!!

**Update:**

I tried changing the code of the javascript function to:

```
var txtfile = "http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/counters/smssender.txt";

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: 'PHP/increment.php',
                data: txtfile,
                success: function() {
                    alert("Download incremented");
                    $.get("http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/counters/smssender.txt", function(data){
                        downcounter = data;
                        if (downcounter == 1)   $("#counter").text("SMS Sender has been downloaded " + downcounter + " time...");   
                        else $("#counter").text("SMS Sender has been downloaded " + downcounter + " times..."); 
                    });
                }               
            });
```

And added a PHP file, increment.php, which has some of the code you gave me here:

```
<? php
    $file = $_POST['txtfile'];
    $counter = intval(file_get_contents($file));
    $counter++;
    file_put_contents($file, $counter);
?>
```

But still, no luck. Would this code work at all or am I misusing references? Thank you

Comment: Looks like your file path is wrong.  `/counters/smssender.txt` refers to a file at your server's filesystem root. Instead this should probably be a file relative to the PHP script like `counters/smssender.txt`.

Comment: Beyond that, you are _well advised_ to verify that the value sent is a plain integer. Otherwise, anyone can write _anything they want_ into your file by passing it in `$_POST['counter']`  Better would be to have the _server_ calculate the new value, rather than submit the new value from the HTTP request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple method of building a counter, but there are a few problems with it.<sup>1</sup>

Instead of relying on the client's JavaScript to supply the value to `counter`, it should be handled entirely on the server side.  If 2 users have the page open simultaneously for example, both would start with the same value, but only increment it by one rather than properly incrementing by one *each*.

This method also avoids the need to sanitize a counter value sent by the client and saved in your file, and avoids the need to process any post at all.  Instead, simply calling the script can increment your counter.

#### Counter PHP script

```
// Does nothing but read and increment the file:
// Read the value
$current_counter = intval(file_get_contents('/path/outside/web/root/counters/smssender.txt'));
// Increment it
$current_counter++;
file_put_contents('/path/outside/web/root/counters/smssender.txt', $current_counter);
// Output it to the client
echo $current_counter;
```

The JavaScript's responsibility is then only to *call* the PHP script, with no parameters.

```
$.get("http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/PHP/smssender.php", function(data) {
  // Do something on success
  console.log(data);
});
```

To protect against direct requests of the `smssender.txt` file, it is recommended to store that file *outside the web server document root*.  Supply the correct path to the file in `file_get_contents()/file_put_contents()`.

To retrieve the current counter value and send it to the client you just need to read and echo the value.

```
echo intval(file_get_contents('/path/outside/web/root/counters/smssender.txt'));
```

Finally, be aware that there's nothing here to prevent anyone from running up your counter by just calling the `smssender.php` script over and over. If you have a login, you should make sure users are signed in when accessing the counter.  Absent a login, you should consider setting a cookie value when the download actually occurs, so you can assert that the user has actually downloaded something in the current session when the counter is incremented.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['some-download-value'])) {
  // Update the counter.
}
```

#### Addendum:

If your web host does not permit you to place files outside the web server document root, you can block direct HTTP requests to the .txt file with a rule like the following in your .htaccess:

```
# Block direct access to any .txt file
<Files ~ "\.txt$">
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>
```

Or you could place the following in a .htaccess file inside the `counters/` directory:

```
# counters/.htaccess
# block all HTTP requests to counter files
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

---

<sup>1</sup> A simpler method, which avoids all the file storage, reading, writing, and security issues is to store the counter value in a database table and `UPDATE` it on each access.

Comment: by 'outside the web server document root', do you mean that the txt file should not be located within any folders?

Comment: I'm so sorry but I think I don't understand. I put up all my files on a 1&1 host site through FileZilla, and the html page where the download button is is smssender.html, at "/". The PHP page is at "/PHP/", and the txt file is at "/counters/"

Comment: @gfcf14 See update above for .htaccess rules to block HTTP access to the file if you can't place it above the doc root.

Comment: I'm sorry again, I've placed an .htaccess file with the first block of code in your addendum under '/' and '/counters/' but my txt file can still be accessed if I input its address manually. Why is this happening?

Comment: my hosting package is windows, but according to 1and1, only linux packages allow .htaccess. In any case, what would be another way to implement a download/visit counter?

Comment: @gfcf14 The other way would be to store the value in a database table and keep updating it there. You then sidestep the file reading, writing, storage, and access issues.  You face the same potential abuse problem though.

Comment: actually, this page http://faq.1and1.com/scripting_languages_supported/htaccess/1.html says only linux packages run apache web servers. Would this be the reason why file writing with the code for the PHP file that you gave me doesn't work?

Comment: @gfcf14 No, PHP is relatively agnostic of the file write.  File _permissions_ may be incorrect though - you may have to make the file writable.

Comment: I changed the txt file permissions to be writable, but still no writing takes place. I did try to see the PHP page entering its URL, and got this : `Warning: file_get_contents(/counters/smssender.txt) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/37/d434704165/htdocs/PHP/smssender.php on line 2

Warning: file_put_contents(/counters/smssender.txt) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/37/d434704165/htdocs/PHP/smssender.php on line 4`

Comment: @gfcf14 You are still using the wrong path.  `/counters/smssender.txt` implies that `/counters` is at the FS root. Your script is executing from `/homepages/37/d434704165/htdocs/PHP` so you could use a path like `file_get_contents('../counters/smssender.txt')` inside the web root, which places it at ` /homepages/37/d434704165/htdocs/counters`, or outside your web root which I assume to be htdocs with `file_get_contents('../../counters/smssender.txt)` which places it at  /homepages/37/d434704165/counters`

Comment: I've changed the php code to read like this: `<?php
 $current_counter = intval(file_get_contents('/homepages/37/d434704165/htdocs/counters/smssender.txt'));
 $current_counter++; 
 file_put_contents('/homepages/37/d434704165/htdocs/counters/smssender.txt', $current_counter);
?>` And I noticed that the file overwrite only occurs if I manually enter the php file's web address. So would the problem be here? `$.get("http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/PHP/smssender.php", function(data)`

Comment: Probably. The JavaScript must be debugged with your browser's console. F12 on most or find developer tools from the menus. Look for any errors or warnings in the JS. You could be having same origin policy problems, for example.  Change the call to a relative path (the web-accessible path) like `$.get('/PHP/smssender.php'), function () {...})`

Comment: We cannot debug this in the comments though.  The moderation tools alert to long comment threads. If you are having a problem with the AJAX call, that belongs in a new question.

Comment: Ok. I will make sure to make a new question and put the page's whole html code there. Thank you so much for all your help!